# How to Move Smart City Columbus from Internal to Open Source?

Tags: project-management, community

Last year, Columbus,OH [won](https://www.transportation.gov/smartcity/winner) the [US DOT Smart Cities Challenge](https://www.transportation.gov/smartcity). Since then, they've made major progress on [a number of fronts](https://smart.columbus.gov/projects/). The [SmartColumbus Operating System](https://www.smartcolumbusos.com/) provides the technical core, while ~1000 data sets populate the potential workspace.

Last week, they put out a [request](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/activity:6458740235097423872/) for advice on moving from internal to open source development. I'm echoing that here:

> A goal of our program is to make the smart city platform we are building openly shareable with other cities so they can benefit from the grant we received from the USDOT.  What we want to do is to move from internal development to open source development and therefore, are looking for people with experience in doing this to advise us.  It would be great to get folks from open source companies as well as from the user/contributor communities. Please pass this on to anyone in your networks that you feel can provide value.  Thank You!

How can Columbus best build an Open Source product to help other cities?

Comment: While definitively an interesting problem, I do not think this question is a good fit for the Stack Exchange model: real questions have (objective) answers. The best questions are based on concrete problems that you yourself have. I have therefore voted to close this question as [“too broad”](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/) or [“primarily opinion-based”](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/). (Those links go to guidance we are using on the Software Engineering site – while not strictly applicable here, they explain some background.)

Comment: Well, @amon, I'm not asking for readers to tell me their preference between Windows and Linux, or what makes a thick-enough chocolate shake. Presumably there a number of steps that experience tells us to look at when transitioning such a project to open source, and I'm asking how to identify those steps.

Comment: Thanks ED, I am looking forward to the contributions your community can add. We want to run a good open source community. Brian

Comment: Thank you for a non-license question!  However, the question you've asked literally requires a book-length answer (if I find the appropriate book, I'll post that as my answer).  Can you narrow it down to specific aspects of the city's transition?

Comment: I'm afraid this community seems to have some rather narrow-minded and power-hungry moderators, which probably explains why its still in beta and seeing mainly license questions. Too bad; I had some pretty interesting challenges in growing an open source community for changing high school. @Brian King , if you can better ask the question, let me know. Thanks, Josh for trying to help.

Comment: @BrianKing if you contact me elsewhere (Josh Berkus, easily findable), I can connect you with professional assistance for moving projects to OSS.

Comment: @EdJones as a member of this community and the technical working group for opening Smart Columbus’s code I agree that this is off topic here. As the question stands, it’s too broad to be answerable. That doesn’t mean specific questions won’t come up that may be appropriate to ask here though. Are you a member of the TWG? I’d love to talk about this.